# AlertDialog does not show dividers on a list

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this class:

```
public class PageDetailInfoView extends FrameLayout {

//few constructors and methods

//method to show an AlertDialog with a list
private void openDialog(){

    List<String> mTags = new ArrayList<String>();
    mTags.add("Item1");
    mTags.add("Item2");
    mTags.add("Item3");
    mTags.add("Item4");
    mTags.add("Item5");
    mTags.add("Item6");

    final CharSequence[] tags = mTags.toArray(new String[mTags.size()]);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Title");
    builder.setItems(tags, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        //do something
        }
    });

    Dialog alertDialogObject = builder.create();
    alertDialogObject.show();


}
```

The Alert dialog is opened after invoke openDialog() but the thing is that it does not exhibit the dividers between items.
I would like to get this:
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-i00d8VG6WsQ/UrGIeyb-8II/AAAAAAAAHwA/8MPWP5qrQ78/s500/alertdialog-with-simple-listview.png

and ,in fact, I get it but without the Gray dividers.
 Any idea about why?

[image]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Change `AlertDialog` List items divider color as:

```
AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();
ListView listView=alertDialogObject.getListView();  
listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE)); // set color
listView.setDividerHeight(2); // set height 
alertDialogObject.show();
```

Comment: Thanks but I  can not access to .getListView()

Comment: This works! But you have to change `Dialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();` to `AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();`

Comment: This works but a line is added at the end of the list too.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because you are running your app on Android 5.0+ which has Material design.

To get the "old" look, just construct your dialog with the Holo style:

```
ContextThemeWrapper themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(themedContext);
// ... then create your dialog
```

Although this might seem weird for some users (especially on Lollipop and Marshmallow, so I recommend looking into using custom views for your dialog.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, good point but does not work, still without dividers :(

Comment: Can you maybe add a screenshot about your current progress?

Comment: screenshot about added

Comment: What are your import statements on the top of the class?

Comment: import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.internal.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

Comment: Looks fine. Please update your post with your latest code (the one with the ContextThemeWrapper).

Comment: Replace Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog_NoActionBar with Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar :)

Comment: But if i want to change only in styles.xml means?