# How to change the divider color of an arraylist in AlertDialog.builder

Tags: android, arraylist, android-alertdialog, builder, divider

I reaaly need your help. I have an AlertDialog that contains an arraylist. I would like to customize line separators of my arraylist.

This is my code.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()); 
List<Tour> listTour = service.getOpenedTours(); 
listProd = new ArrayList<Producer>();
 builder.setTitle("Selectionner un producteur"); 
float[] res = new float[3];
 List<Producer> producers = new ArrayList<Producer>(); 
String prods = listProd.toString(); 
CharSequence[] cs = prods.split(", "); 
builder.setItems(cs, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{ 
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
 {

 });
 builder.create().show(); 
}
 }
```

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500765/alertdialog-does-not-show-dividers-on-a-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using arraylist to ListView then you need to set divider color of `ListView` as below:

**Edit**

```
AlertDialog alertDialogObject = dialogBuilder.create();
ListView listView=alertDialogObject.getListView();  
listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)); // set color
alertDialogObject.show();
```

Comment: I'm not usinf List View

Comment: Then how are you populating your arraylist over dialog? and how the dividers are coming?

Comment: @HajarAmmoumri Well you can't get dividers until you use listView. So better you use ListView in AlertDialog.